# Array.find() gets correct value but returns wrong one

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I thought it would be fun to write a few Array methods to help with sorting and grouping objects. Here's my code. Please excuse the `log`s, this is driving me bananas. You can run this code on JSBin, [here](http://jsbin.com/kajici/21/edit?js,output).

```
/**
 * uniquePush method - conditionally add an object to an array
 *
 * Only adds an object if it is not already present on this array.
 * Doesn't do a deep comparison.
 * 
 * @param {Object} newElement - the element to check for before pushing
 * @returns {Array} the array, modified if nescessary
 */
Array.prototype.uniquePush = function (newElement) {
  console.dir(this);
  var findCount = 0;

  function findNewElement(element) {
    console.log("findCount: " + (++findCount));
    console.log("Element: " + element);
    console.log("newElement: " + newElement);
    var found = (element === newElement);
    console.log("findNewElement -> " + found);
    return found;
  }

  var foundNewElement = this.find(findNewElement);
  console.log("this.find(findNewElement): " + foundNewElement)
  if (foundNewElement) {
    // Found it. Don't add it.
    console.log("Declined to add \'" + newElement + "\' to array");
  } else {
    // Didn't find it, go ahead and add it
    console.log("Adding \'" + newElement + "\' to array");
  }

  console.log("---------------------------------");
  return (foundNewElement ? this : this.push(newElement));
}

/**
 * groupBy method - groups an array of objects by property value
 *
 * Returned Array will look like:
 * [
 *  [{prop: "propValue", ...}, {prop: "propValue", ...}],
 *  [{prop: "anotherValue", ...}, {prop: "anotherValue", ...}],
 *  ...
 *  [{prop: "nValue", ...}, {prop: "nValue", ...}]
 * ]
 *
 * @param {String} prop - the property to group by
 * @returns {Array} an Array containing the grouped arrays
 */
Array.prototype.groupBy = function (prop) {
  // Gather all the possible property values
  var propValues = [];
  var entries = this.entries();

  var entryValue;
  while (entryValue = entries.next().value) {
    propValues.uniquePush(entryValue[1][prop]);
  }

  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < propValues.length; i += 1) {
    var innerResult = [];
    this.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element[prop] === this.propValue) {
        this.result.push(element);
      }
    }, {
      propValue: propValues[i], 
      result: innerResult
    });
    result.push(innerResult);
  }
  return result;
};

var PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

var groupedByCategory = PRODUCTS.groupBy("category");
console.dir(groupedByCategory);
var groupedByStocked = PRODUCTS.groupBy("stocked");
console.dir(groupedByStocked);
```

This code mostly works okay, but I find it has trouble on arrays of boolean values. Specifically, the `uniquePush()` method uses the `Array.find()` method to determine whether or not a given `newElement` is present in `this` array.

However, it seems like it's returning the wrong value. When I run it on `"stocked"` for example, I get this:

```
<edited for brevity>

[true, false]
"findCount: 1"
"Element: true"
"newElement: true"
"findNewElement -> true"
"foundNewElement: true"
"---------------------------------"
"Declined to add true to array"
[true, false]
"findCount: 1"
"Element: true"
"newElement: false"
"findNewElement -> false"
"findCount: 2"
"Element: false"
"newElement: false"
"findNewElement -> true"
"foundNewElement: false"
"---------------------------------"
"Adding false to array"
[true, false, false]
```

As you can see, at the end, `findNewElement` is evaluated to `true` yet `Array.find()` returns `false`. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: indexOf() should be used if you're searching for whole elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns undefined if nothing was found.

```
var foundNewElement = this.find(findNewElement);
  if (foundNewElement) ...
```

if it finds 'false' this check fails. Use `if (typeof(foundElement)!='undefined')`

Comment: If `newElement === undefined`, you won't know if you found it or not.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can find something undefined, logically speaking :) I thought about that and dismissed it as silly. And I am a bit old school, so `=== undefined`, while it works nowadays, it didn't use to work historically, when you could do undefined=2 in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood [`[].find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). It's used to retrieve the first value which satisfies some condition, not to check if a value belongs to an array.

If you want to do the latter, you can use

- ES5 [`[].indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill). Compares with the [Strict Equality](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) algorithm.

  ```
  myArray.indexOf(value) > -1
  ```
- ES6 [`[].findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). You can provide your own comparator function.

  ```
  myArray.findIndex(item => item === value) > -1
  ```
- ES7 [`[].includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Compares with the [SameValueZero](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm.

  ```
  myArray.includes(value)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You code is way to messed up.
Here is a simple solution you may like.

```
Array.prototype.uniquePush = function (newElement) {
  return this.indexOf(newElement) !== -1 ? this : this.push(newElement);
}
```

https://jsbin.com/nexuboqavo/edit?html,output

Comment: Will this work on non-indexed array elements? Like say `array["some string"]`?

Comment: No :) 
This is for simple array. If you want to support objects you can also do it easily with Object.keys (will return the array of keys) ...